# Sonar Maven not working (org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7:sonar (default-cli)

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonar-maven-plugin

I see I am not the only one having this problem from 14 hours ago.

At my office, other projects are failing too but the message shown make reference to sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7:sonar (default-cli) on project x: Unable to determine structure of project.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, what is your project structure? And what command did you use to launch the Sonar analysis?

Comment: We deploy the wars into an oc4j, it fails while the maven command "compile" is running. I think it´s the same fail that is appearing in the internet from yesterday afternoon. I hope an answer will appear until monday

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sonar.host.url not working with sonar-maven-plugin:2.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297020/sonar-host-url-not-working-with-sonar-maven-plugin2-7)

Answer (score 5):

Define in your parent pom.xml the previous version of the plugin, it seems the latest version 2.7 has an issue you can pin the version like this :

```
<pluginManagement>
 <plugins>
:
:
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.6</version>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Comment: @Frank_Nela: Did you try to pin the Version as I have recommended? If no version is defined, maven always get the latest Version. The latest Version has an issue. So pinning the Version to the previous one should solve your problem. You can easily pin the version as I described in  my response. Please mark my answer as the right one if it solved your problem. thanx

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in 2.7.1. You can check this [JIRA](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MSONAR-130) issue.

Comment: Just hit it with 2.7.1

Answer (score 0):

I just got hit with this issue. There's some issue with the 2.7 plugin so I tried forcing Maven to use the 2.6 plugin via the command line as below. Or you can add to pom.xml

->  mvn org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar

Answer (score 0):

It seems downgrading the plugin from 2.7 to 2.6 at jenkins/configure in the server solves the issue.

Thanks to all!

Comment: Glad a downgrade from 2.7 to version 2.6 solved the issue. Would you mind to press the green check-mark left side of my answer? That would be very nice :) Thank you very much.