# With sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1 fixed what should I upgrade to get it?

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I followed the question [sonar.host.url not working with sonar-maven-plugin:2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297020/sonar-host-url-not-working-with-sonar-maven-plugin2-7) to find that SonarQube have now fixed https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MSONAR-129. My pom doesn't explicitly include the sonar-maven-plugin, so what tool should I upgrade to what release to get the fix? Do I need to add 2.7.1 explicitly in my pom, or pick up another new plugin?

(I don't have the rep yet to comment on Julien's link, thus the separate question.)

Update: I tried explicitly using 2.7.1 but it isn't available. When will it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks available now. You might have to force it to download again by deleting your local copies in your repo.

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.codehaus.mojo|sonar-maven-plugin|2.7.1|maven-plugin

Good luck!