# hudson: maven-sonar-plugin execution fails to download libraries from server

Tags: maven, sonarqube, hudson

I have a hudson jobs doing the sonar stats for a maven project.

The execution of the sonar plugin fails with the following trace

```
    [workspace] $ /hudson/hudson1/hudson/tools/maven-3.0.4/bin/mvn -f /hudson/hudson1/hudson/jobs/15_20_NX_Core_Quality/workspace/pom.xml -e -B sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jdbc.password= -Dsonar.forceAnalysis=true -Dsonar.login=admin -Dsonar.password=admin -Dsonar.jdbc.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://VX16:1433;databaseName=Sonar2;SelectMethod=Cursor ******** -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:8080/sonar ******** ********
    [INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Reactor Build Order:
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] NX Core
    [INFO] core-entity
    [INFO] core-logic
    [INFO] core-ui
    [WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
    [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0: Plugin org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building NX Core 1.22.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
    [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0: Plugin org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar (default-cli) @ core ---
    [INFO] User cache: /home/jetty/.sonar/cache
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Reactor Summary:
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] NX Core ........................................... FAILURE [1.414s]
    [INFO] core-entity ....................................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] core-logic ........................................ SKIPPED
    [INFO] core-ui ........................................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 2.490s
    [INFO] Finished at: Wed Oct 28 14:10:38 CET 2015
    [INFO] Final Memory: 14M/303M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar (default-cli) on project core: Fail to download libraries from server: Status returned by url : 'http://localhost:8080/sonar/batch_bootstrap/index' is invalid : 404 -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar (default-cli) on project core: Fail to download libraries from server
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fail to download libraries from server
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:41)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstrapper.execute(RunnerBootstrapper.java:104)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:135)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to download libraries from server
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.Jars.dowloadFiles(Jars.java:94)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.Jars.download(Jars.java:71)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:40)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:91)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:87)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:87)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:83)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doStart(EmbeddedRunner.java:250)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.start(EmbeddedRunner.java:188)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.start(EmbeddedRunner.java:183)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstrapper.execute(RunnerBootstrapper.java:77)
        ... 22 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Status returned by url : 'http://localhost:8080/sonar/batch_bootstrap/index' is invalid : 404
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:95)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerConnection.tryServerFirst(ServerConnection.java:163)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerConnection.loadString(ServerConnection.java:142)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.Jars.dowloadFiles(Jars.java:79)
        ... 33 more
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
    Sonar analysis completed: FAILURE
    Finished: FAILURE
```

The execution of the plugin fails since 8 days, neither the pom, nor the project changed since this point of time.

sonar system specs

```
    System date,Wed Oct 28 14:34:36 CET 2015
    JVM Vendor,Oracle Corporation
    JVM Name,Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
    JVM Version,23.6-b04
    Java Version,1.7.0_10-b18
    Java Home,/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/jre
    JIT Compiler,-
    Application Server Container,Apache Tomcat/7.0.35
    User Name,tomcat7
    User TimeZone,Europe/Zurich
    OS,Linux / amd64 / 3.2.0-92-generic
    Processors,4
    System Classpath,/tomcat/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/tomcat/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
    Boot Classpath,/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/jre/classes
    Library Path,/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
    Server ID,-
    Version,3.4.1
    Started at,Wed Oct 28 14:09:46 CET 2015
    Database,Microsoft SQL Server 10.50.2500
    Database URL,jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://VX16:1433/Sonar2
    Database Login,sa
    Database Driver,jTDS Type 4 JDBC Driver for MS SQL Server and Sybase 1.2.4
    Database Driver Class,net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
    Database Dialect (Hibernate),mssql (org.sonar.core.persistence.dialect.MsSql$MsSqlDialect)
    Hibernate Default Schema,-
    External User Authentication,-
    Automatic User Creation,-
    Allow Users to Sign Up,-
    Force Authentication,-
    Total Memory,445 MB
    Free Memory,219 MB
    Max Memory,954 MB
    Heap,init = 262973312(256809K) used = 225130168(219853K) committed = 445120512(434688K) max = 954466304(932096K)
    Non Heap,init = 24313856(23744K) used = 80584792(78696K) committed = 80805888(78912K) max = 136314880(133120K)
    System Load Average (last minute),8.0%
    Loaded Classes (currently/total/unloaded),13535 / 13535 / 0
    Start Time,2015-10-28T14:09:37.964+0100
    Threads (total/peak/daemon),23 / 23 / 21
    Checkstyle,1.1
    Cobertura,1.1
    Findbugs,1.1
    JaCoCo,1.1
    Java,1.1
    PMD,1.1
    Squid for Java,1.1
    Surefire,1.1
    SONAR_HOME,/tomcat/sonar
    awt.toolkit,sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
    catalina.base,/tomcat/tomcat7
    catalina.home,/tomcat/tomcat7
    catalina.useNaming,true
    common.loader,"${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar"
    file.encoding,UTF-8
    file.encoding.pkg,sun.io
    file.separator,/
    java.awt.graphicsenv,sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
    java.awt.headless,true
    java.awt.printerjob,sun.print.PSPrinterJob
    java.class.path,/tomcat/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/tomcat/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
    java.class.version,51.0
    java.endorsed.dirs,/tomcat/tomcat7/endorsed
    java.ext.dirs,/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
    java.home,/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/jre
    java.io.tmpdir,/tmp/tomcat7-tmp
    java.library.path,/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
    java.naming.factory.initial,org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory
    java.naming.factory.url.pkgs,org.apache.naming
    java.runtime.name,Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
    java.runtime.version,1.7.0_10-b18
    java.specification.name,Java Platform API Specification
    java.specification.vendor,Oracle Corporation
    java.specification.version,1.7
    java.util.logging.config.file,/tomcat/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties
    java.util.logging.manager,org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
    java.vendor,Oracle Corporation
    java.vendor.url,http://java.oracle.com/
    java.vendor.url.bug,http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
    java.version,1.7.0_10
    java.vm.info,mixed mode
    java.vm.name,Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
    java.vm.specification.name,Java Virtual Machine Specification
    java.vm.specification.vendor,Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.specification.version,1.7
    java.vm.vendor,Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.version,23.6-b04
    jruby.management.enabled,true
    line.separator,"
    "
    org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.jarsToSkip,""
    org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.jarsToSkip,""
    os.arch,amd64
    os.name,Linux
    os.version,3.2.0-92-generic
    package.access,sun.,org.apache.catalina.,org.apache.coyote.,org.apache.tomcat.,org.apache.jasper."""
    package.definition,"sun.,java.,org.apache.catalina.,org.apache.coyote.,org.apache.tomcat.,org.apache.jasper."
    path.separator,:
    server.loader,""
    shared.loader,""
    sun.arch.data.model,64
    sun.boot.class.path,/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/jre/classes
    sun.boot.library.path,/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/jre/lib/amd64
    sun.cpu.endian,little
    sun.cpu.isalist,""
    sun.font.fontmanager,sun.awt.X11FontManager
    sun.io.unicode.encoding,UnicodeLittle
    sun.java.command,org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
    sun.java.launcher,SUN_STANDARD
    sun.jnu.encoding,UTF-8
    sun.management.compiler,HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
    sun.os.patch.level,unknown
    tomcat.util.buf.StringCache.byte.enabled,true
    tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip,"bootstrap.jar,commons-daemon.jar,tomcat-juli.jar,annotations-api.jar,el-api.jar,jsp-api.jar,servlet-api.jar,catalina.jar,catalina-ant.jar,catalina-ha.jar,catalina-tribes.jar,jasper.jar,jasper-el.jar,ecj-*.jar,tomcat-api.jar,tomcat-util.jar,tomcat-coyote.jar,tomcat-dbcp.jar,tomcat-jni.jar,tomcat-spdy.jar,tomcat-i18n-en.jar,tomcat-i18n-es.jar,tomcat-i18n-fr.jar,tomcat-i18n-ja.jar,tomcat-juli-adapters.jar,catalina-jmx-remote.jar,catalina-ws.jar,tomcat-jdbc.jar,commons-beanutils*.jar,commons-codec*.jar,commons-collections*.jar,commons-dbcp*.jar,commons-digester*.jar,commons-fileupload*.jar,commons-httpclient*.jar,commons-io*.jar,commons-lang*.jar,commons-logging*.jar,commons-math*.jar,commons-pool*.jar,jstl.jar,geronimo-spec-jaxrpc*.jar,wsdl4j*.jar,ant.jar,ant-junit*.jar,aspectj*.jar,jmx.jar,h2*.jar,hibernate*.jar,httpclient*.jar,jmx-tools.jar,jta*.jar,log4j*.jar,mail*.jar,slf4j*.jar,xercesImpl.jar,xmlParserAPIs.jar,xml-apis.jar,access-bridge.jar,access-bridge-64.jar,dnsns.jar,jaccess.jar,ldapsec.jar,localedata.jar,sunjce_provider.jar,sunmscapi.jar,sunpkcs11.jar,jhall.jar,tools.jar,sunec.jar,zipfs.jar,gnome-java-bridge.jar,pulse-java.jar,apple_provider.jar,AppleScriptEngine.jar,CoreAudio.jar,dns_sd.jar,j3daudio.jar,j3dcore.jar,j3dutils.jar,jai_core.jar,jai_codec.jar,mlibwrapper_jai.jar,MRJToolkit.jar,vecmath.jar,junit.jar,junit-*.jar,ant-launcher.jar"
    user.country,US
    user.dir,/tomcat/tomcat7
    user.home,/home/tomcat7
    user.language,en
    user.name,tomcat7
    user.timezone,Europe/Zurich
```

Any help is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Well something must have changed: this URL `http://localhost:8080/sonar/batch_bootstrap/index'` is returning 404, i.e. the URL does not exist.

Comment: yep, I curled this URL with/without credentials getting the 404, but sonar/batch_bootstrap/index is no static resource but dynamic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sonar.host.url not working with sonar-maven-plugin:2.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297020/sonar-host-url-not-working-with-sonar-maven-plugin2-7)

Answer (score 3):

Too bad 2.7.1 is not back-compatible.
Lock your plugin version to 2.6 in your pom.xml or upgrade your SonarQube

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/HOME/Frequently+Asked+Questions

Answer (score 0):

You're using a very very old version of SonarQube. I highly recommend you to upgrade. If you still want to remain on your version of SonarQube, you can try to downgrade sonar-maven-plugin to version 2.6.